# Animated PPT presenation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm currently working on a school presentation and I want to make it a little more special. I've seen [this](https://youtu.be/_lsGT_AqnxE) video and it is amazing.

What I don't understand is, how would one make an object be animated such as the one at the second 40? Another thing, how could I make a shape grow such as the one at the second 17, to cover the entire screen, without losing quality? Even a simple circle shape looks extremely blurry when using the Grow/Shrink animation.

Sadly, it has to be made in PowerPoint.

Thank you!

Comment: If you look under the video you can see it's done using a 3rd-party product.

Comment: But it says in the video description: "_All shapes and animations were made using PowerPoint_". Also, on the presentation description page, it says: "_All elements, shapes, animations are done using PowerPoint and should be playable on PowerPoint 2010 and 2013 versions_". So it should be possible to recreate such shapes and animations in PowerPoint.

Comment: I believe that it has been exported to PowerPoint more than being created using it. As you mentioned it, smoothness in second 17 is possible more with Flash than PowerPoint. However, you can use a GIF to make the same effect like in second 40.